# Detecting errors in Core Data lightweight migration

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, migration

I am using lightweight migration to update my model for the first time. Testing updates from previous version seems fine, but I would like to be able to trap failures and log them.

How and where can I intercept any migration errors before the app crashes?

Comment: Where do you want to log those errors? In production or during testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben,

Lightweight migration occurs when the store is connected to the coordinator using the `-addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:` method. You can catch your errors here.

Andrew